# QGIS 2.18.15 georeferencer fail

Tags: qgis

I have recently purchased a Phantom 4 pro, and am reliving my 35 year ago survey life, but am having problems with QGIS!

I have both jpeg and tiff ortho images saved by Agisoft Standard which appear to be OK! I have the openlayers plugin and georeferncer plugins installed in QGIS and both appear to be working.

I live in Western Australia so I have set both defaults to epsg.28350 94 zone 50.

I can load the google background and then can load the georeferencer image, both jpg and tiff. I do the gcp's and hit the transformation button with the button checked to install the image in QGIS. The image then appears to be installed in QGIS, but all I have is a blank white background with the red gcp' points on the geotiff image in QGIS. However when I look in my windows file manager I can see a distorted image

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that the images are paletted. You need to transform them to RGB before georeferencing. Otherwise interpolating of cell values will not work.

Comment: A big thanks for your support AndreJ, but I just checked out the images and they are not paletted! I have just re-installed QGIS to see if I have other problems.